# Java Recursive Backtracking

Tags: java, recursive-backtracking

I study computer sciene and I'm currently practising backtracking as I#m very bad at it.
I found that exercise online:

You are selling apples. This is a current price tables for your apples:

Count 1 2 3 4 5  6  7  8
Price 1 5 8 9 10 17 17 20

So if you're selling 8 apples at once, you'll get 20$.
If you're selling 6 and then 2 instead, you'll get 22$.
Try to find the maximum profit.
Here's the method, you should use:

```
public static long sellApples(int count, long[] prices) {

}
```

Now I thought about that like 5 hours, but I can't come to a good solution.
Anyone up for a little challenge?

Comment: Have you tried anything beyond that method stub yet?

Comment: you need to split count into pieces, like `8` into `3, 5`. Then you need to call this method with both of these numbers as parameters and sum the result.

Comment: @MTCoster No, I try to stick to the exercise there.

Comment: @LászlóStahorszki Yeah, that's what i thought about too, but I don't know how to implement that properly...

Comment: What I meant is, have you written any additional code which you haven’t posted here?

Comment: @MTCoster 
    public static long verkaufenNaive(int stoff, long[] preise) {
        if(stoff <= 0) return 0L;
        else {
            if()
        }
    }

Comment: @waayne The point I’m trying to make is that *we are not here to write your code for you*. SO is a place to get help with code you’ve *already written* and can’t get working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this subject, so take what I say with a grain of salt.

In the method, you need to split count into pieces, like `8 => 3, 5`. You need to call this method again, with both of these values as `count`. That is the more obvious part.

The tricky part is that you need to admit that splitting count into 2 parts is enough. I mean that you don't need to try calling the method with `1,2,5` values, because if you just call it with `3,5`, then the next iteration can split `3` into `1,2`.

A bit more obvious fact is that if you tried `3,5` then you don't need to try `5,3`.

So if your input is 8, then you try `8`, `1,7`, `2,6`, `3,5`, `4,4` and compare the results, choosing the biggest one. From the method stub you provided, I assume that you don't need to return how you got to that result, just the max result itself

Comment: But what if the best price / apple is when selling them in pairs, then the optimal combination would be 2-2-2-2?

Comment: yes. Then the program would split the original input `8` into `4,4` in the first iteration, and the second iteration would split `4` into `2,2` both times. The program would try splitting 2 into `1,1`, but that would be smaller than the original `2`, which will be the return value

Comment: I realize that this is probably an O(2^n) algorithm (I haven't checked). But it's better then no algorithm I guess

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help you.

```
    public static long sellApples(int count, long[] prices) {
    long maxKnownValue = 0L;
    if(count==1){
        return prices[0];
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=prices.length && i<=count;i++){
        long valueCandidate = sellApples(count-i, prices)+prices[i-1];
        if(valueCandidate>maxKnownValue){
            maxKnownValue=valueCandidate;
        }
    }
    return maxKnownValue;
}
```

Comment: I've did _some_ testing here. So pls. test and check if there any errors.

Comment: 2 reasons why I down voted: it's wrong, because it doesn't check if a given count is better then splitting it, which means that the result is just prices[0]×count. The second reason is that you're not meant to solve other ppls homework, just help them if they get stuck

Comment: Do you think that the result is just prices[0]×count? Read the code. Carefully. Again.

Comment: @dlavochkin You definitely have the best bio on Stack Overflow.